# Convert value in dictionaries from a list of dictionaries from a string to integer

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion, integer

I have a list of dictionaries, where the key and values are both strings.
However, I want to convert the value from a string to a int.

I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to be working, either I receive 'key error: '1' or 'size of dictionary has changed'.

My dictionary looks like this (I have total 54 dictionaries)

```
{'1A': '1',
 '3E': '2',
 'PRODUCT NUMBER': '1',
 'Week': '1'},
 {'1A': '1',
  '1B': '1',
  '1C': '1',
  '1D': '2',
  '1E': '2',
  '2C': '1',
  '3E': '2',
  'PRODUCT NUMBER': '2',
  'Week': '1'},
```

and so on.

My code:

```
import csv
import pprint
from typing import List, Dict

input_file_1 = csv.DictReader(open("DATA CWK SHOPPING DATA WEEK 1 FILE B.xlsb.csv"))

table = list(input_file_1)

buyers = []
for row in table:
    buyers_list = {}
    for i in row:
        if row[i] != '' and i != 'PRODUCT NAME':
            buyers_list.update({i : row[i]})
    buyers.append(buyers_list)

pprint.pprint(buyers)
```

Comment: How would replacing `row[i]` with `row[i]` convert a string to an int? Where is your integer conversion actually happening?

Comment: the conversion isnt happening in the code ive provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [{'1A': '1','3E': '2','PRODUCT NUMBER': '1', 'Week': '1'},
       {'1A': '1','1B': '1','1C': '1','1D': '2','1E': '2','2C': '1',
        '3E': '2','PRODUCT NUMBER': '2','Week': '1'}]

for k in my_list:
    for t in k.keys():
        k[t] = int(k[t])
```

This program will do your work.

Comment: Even this post works, but it's hard to read?  First of all, the `k` in the for-loop is really a dictionary, right?  It's prob. better to name it accordingly to reflect what's it there.

Comment: Do you not want the second for loop to be 'k.values()' ? this returns me an error "KeyError: '1'"

Comment: You might have misunderstood something. First, I put dictionaries in a list. Then I looped through dictionaries (k) in the list. Second list is over keys (t) of dictionaries (k). Then what I did, I replaced the values in dictionary. Here, I have taken int(str). k[t] is value, and I took int of that. It is unreadable but give some effort, you will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:  (assuming all key are valid `int` - or you have to do some *checking* like `try`... `except`.):

```
# lst is your dictionary
for sub in lst:  # sub is a dict
    for key, val in sub.items():
        print(key, val)           # can comment out later. .
        sub[key] = int(val)
```

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused, so sub is an empty dictionary? and the keys are not valid ints, but all the values are